# setInterval callback that calls another callback function is not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here is my code

```
function doIt(context, startTime) {
    context.url((currentURL) => {
        console.log("URL: " + currentURL.value)
    })
    console.log("running timer function ")
    if (new Date() - startTime > 5000) { // timeout = 5 seconds
        console.log("timed out")
        clearInterval(timerId) // exit the loop
    } else {
        console.log("keep on truckin'")
    }
}

let timerId = setInterval(doIt, 1000, this, Date.now())
```

Instead of looping five times (once per second for 5 seconds), it is only running once and the output comes out as ...

```
running timer function
keep on truckin'
URL: https://michigan.magellanrx.com/
```

If I comment out the first 3 lines of code (the context.url function) then the code runs as expected with the output ...

```
running timer function
keep on truckin'
running timer function
keep on truckin'
running timer function
keep on truckin'
running timer function
keep on truckin'
running timer function
timed out
```

Why isn't the code running through all five iterations when the context.url function isn't commented out?

Clarification on this ... it turns out it's not running just once.  Indeed, what is happening is that the setInterval function is changing from a "blocking" function to a "non-blocking" function when those first 3 lines of code are included.  So, instead of running through all five iterations before moving on, it's only running the first iteration then moving on to subsequent commands while the setInterval continues to run in the background.

Comment: What does `context.url()` do?

Comment: Does it perform a redirect?

Comment: If it does a redirect, that will cancel the JavaScript running on this page.

Comment: context.url() retrieves the current url.  'context' is a browser instance.

Comment: Post the code, something in there is interfering.

Comment: `this` appears to be in the global context.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the symptom it sounds like you may have **an infinite loop** in `context.url()`.

Infinite loops blocks the main thread, thereby causing no events to be processed. You need to find and remove that infinite loop.

---

#### How javascript is implemented in C/C++

The way the javascript interpreter is implemented is usually something like the following:

```
// pseudocode:
do {
    eventHandlers = executeJavascript();
    // end of execution

    events = waitForAllIO(); // this actually blocks but it is waiting
                             // for ALL I/O instead of just one

    if (events.timeout) {
        foreach (callback from eventHandlers) {
            if (callback is TIMEOUT_HANDLER) {
                callback(events.timeout);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach (event from events) {
             foreach (callback from eventHandlers) {
                 if (callback is for event) {
                     callback(event);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
} while (eventHandlers.length > 0)
```

If your code is executing an infinite loop, that means the interpreter gets stuck at the `executeJavascript()` part. That means no timers or network packets or any other events gets processed. Which explains why your `setInterval` only produces an output once.